# Jackson: Deserializing a Set?

Tags: set, jackson

When I attempt to deserialize:

```
{
  "tags": {}
}
```

into:

```
public static class Foo
{
    private final Set<URI> tags;

    /**
     * Creates a new Foo entity.
     * <p/>
     * @param tags the room tags
     * @throws NullPointerException if tags is null
     */
    @JsonCreator
    public Foo(@JsonProperty("tags") Set<URI> tags)
    {
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(tags, "tags may not be null");

        this.tags = ImmutableSet.copyOf(tags);
    }

    /**
     * @return the tags
     */
    public Set<URI> getTags()
    {
        return tags;
    }
}
```

I get:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.HashSet out of START_OBJECT token
 at [line: 1, column: 2]
```

Shouldn't this work out-of-the-box?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this to work you need to convert to an array:

```
{
  "tags": []
}
```

If not, how would you represent multiple elements in the tags set using valid JSON?

Comment: Wow I'm so blind. I thought I **was** using an array :) Thank you for pointing out the typo!

Answer (score 0):

My problem was with mapping the payload, make sure that:

- The fields are the same (payload and object) or you are using @JsonProperty correctly
- You need to create setters on your object to framework fill the fields

I hope it helps